# the method sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN) is not working when I execute my code on a server

Tags: java, selenium

I'm using the method sendkey() and in local it works, but when I execute the same code on remote on a server, I have this error:

```
Element <div id="react-select-2--value" class="Select-multi-value-wrapper"> is not reachable by keyboard
```

```
driver.findElement(selectChurnReason).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have jumped to the wrong conclusion here - the error message is telling you that the *element* is not reachable, which means it's likely either not being displayed currently, off the screen, or is behind some kind of overlay.

There's nothing there to select the arrow down key couldn't be emulated.

Comment: how do you explain that it works on local but not on the server?

Comment: @BenMustaphaSabrine At a guess, your emulated browser window on the server could be much smaller than your local one, meaning it's off-screen by default.